# Checking dictionary value list for matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

Hello new to programming and python here. I'm trying to make a program that will take a list of keys and values; then add those items to a dictionary. The program should check each value against current values in a dictionary before appending it to the key. Here is my code so far.

```
finalList= {'turtle':['turtle10']}

keyList = ['turtle','cat','mouse','dog']
valueList =['turtle1','turtle2','turtle1','cat1','cat2','dog','dog1']
for i in keyList:
    finalList[i]= []

 for items in finalList.keys():
    #print('***Keys***'+items)
     for elements in valueList:
         #print('***Values***'+elements)
         res = not any(finalList.values())
         if items in elements:
            
             if elements not in finalList.values():
                finalList[items].append(elements)

            
            
        

    

print(finalList)




Output = {'turtle': ['turtle1', 'turtle2', 'turtle1'], 'cat': ['cat1', 'cat2'], 'mouse': [], 'dog': ['dog', 'dog1']}
```

Why did my final if statement not check the values already in the dictionary? And if there is a better way to do them please let me know. I know this community is filled will seasoned developers; but I am clearly not, so please take it easy on me. THANK YOU!

Comment: convert your `list` to `set` and it will make sure there will be single value.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by that. Where do I do that at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your last if there should be:

`if elements not in finalList[items]:` rather than

`if elements not in finalList.values():`

Comment: I wish i could upvote it but not enough rep.

Comment: upvote from me then ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can make this more concise with dictionary and set comprehension:

```
finalList = {i : list({j for j in valueList if i in j}) for i in keyList} #Actually a dictionary but whatever
```

Output:

```
{'turtle': ['turtle1', 'turtle2'],
 'cat': ['cat2', 'cat1'],
 'mouse': [],
 'dog': ['dog', 'dog1']}
```

Comment: This is more than true to do in very pythonic way. However the author is new to programming and trying to work / understand basic workflow concepts, that proposition may not be too clear for a beginner :D